# Python script liking to GUI using IDE

Tags: python, scripts, gui, ide

I am studying python. Now I can write python scripts (codes) to some extent. I used **IDLE** for this.

I am interested in making GUI to those written programs. I like to do it using an IDE rather than using PyGTK or Tkinter.

Can anyone help me how to start with this and link my scripts to a GUI?

I downloaded a IDE called **glade**, but I don't know how to use this IDE. I need some tutorial guide also. Can anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Eclipse. It is easy to use and works on all platform. If you want tutorial then here it is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSkNj2ACTRQ . But glade also works fine

You can use tkinter for GUI programming. it is little a bit easier than other.

Comment: Do you have a step by step tutorial for glade or tkinter?

And how should I attach python scripts to glade?

Comment: Try this http://www.pygtk.org/articles/pygtk-glade-gui/Creating_a_GUI_using_PyGTK_and_Glade.htm